# Bit Shifting wrong value

Tags: java

I have a problem, I need to convert coordinates using shift, and after that convert them back to original but it returns not the same value (min,max values can't be changed..).

```
int x = 1000;
int y = -1000;

int minx = -294912; // can't be changed.
int miny = -262144; // can't be changed.

//Convert
int convertedX = x - minx >> 4;
int convertedY = y - miny >> 4;

//Convert back
int originalX = (convertedX << 4) + minx;
int originalY = (convertedY << 4) + miny;

System.out.println(originalX + " " + originalY + " - After Convert Back");
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need a binary shift and not merely a decimal shift? What is your expected value of convertedX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your shift is effectively dividing by 16... so you end up losing information. You can't exactly represent any values which aren't exactly divisible by 16 (i.e. values which don't have the bottom four bits as 0000.)

If you don't want to lose information, you can't apply that shift - it's as simple as that.

(Personally I'd *also* put brackets around `x - minx` to make the precedence clear. That isn't actually causing you problems, but unless people have learned the precedence rules, the code isn't clear.)

Comment: Is there is a way to make same calculation without loosing information?

Comment: @Wanna: If by "the same calculation" you include "shifting right by four bits" then no. Think about it - shift "10000" and "10101" right four bits... you get the same output for two different inputs. That means you can't possibly get back to the original inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You are losing information when you bit-shift to the right by 4.  For the values of `1000` and `-1000`, there is 1 bit -- the 4th from the right -- that is lost.

I get the same values if I change all bit-shift amounts to 3, or if I change both `x` and `y` to a multiple of 16, so that the last 4 bits are all zero and no information is lost.